# How to Selected Option with value option in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="idVungxa">Phường</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="idVungxa" id="idVungxa" ng-model="idVungxa">
      <option ng-repeat="vungxa in vungxas" value='{{vungxa.idVungxa}}' >{{vungxa.tenVungxa}}</option>
   </select><br>                
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("idVungxa").value = track.vungxa.idVungxa;
```

It not display vungxa.tenVungxa in Web when i pass value.
Help me. Tks all

Comment: Honestly not sure what you are attempting with your script. Can you explain your issue more clearly? Are the options displaying correctly in the view? 

It almost looks like you are trying to set the ng-model of the select. Are you trying to set the model do a default selection? Or is the select simply not working? Showing your controller would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
document.getElementById("idVungxa").value = track.vungxa.idVungxa;
```

I dont know if the above code works but if you want to set value on model "idVungxa" you should use this code.

```
$scope.idVungxa = track.vungxa.idVungxa;
```